# Avoid repetition in Angular controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm an angular newbie and I'm writing an Ionic app. 
I finished my app and am trying to refactor my controller avoiding code repetition.

I have this piece of code that manages my modal:

```
 angular.module('starter')
  .controller('NewsCtrl', function($scope, content, $cordovaSocialSharing, $timeout, $sce, $ionicModal){
    $scope.news = content;

    content.getList('comments').then(function (comments) {
      $scope.comments = comments;
    });

    $scope.addComment = function() {

    };

    $scope.shareAnywhere = function() {
        $cordovaSocialSharing.share("Guarda questo articolo pubblicato da DDay", "Ti stanno segnalando questo articolo", content.thumbnail, "http://blog.nraboy.com");
    };

    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/comments.html', {
      scope: $scope,
      animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function(modal) {
      $scope.modal = modal;
    });

    $scope.showComment = function() {
      $scope.modal.show();
    };

    // Triggered in the login modal to close it
    $scope.closeComment = function() {
      $scope.modal.hide();
    };

    $scope.$on('modal.shown', function() {
      var footerBar; 
      var scroller;
      var txtInput;

      $timeout(function() {
        footerBar = document.body.querySelector('#commentView .bar-footer');
        scroller = document.body.querySelector('#commentView .scroll-content');
        txtInput = angular.element(footerBar.querySelector('textarea'));
      }, 0);

      $scope.$on('taResize', function(e, ta) {        
        if (!ta) return;   
        var taHeight = ta[0].offsetHeight;        
        if (!footerBar) return;
        var newFooterHeight = taHeight + 10;
        newFooterHeight = (newFooterHeight > 44) ? newFooterHeight : 44;

        footerBar.style.height = newFooterHeight + 'px';
        scroller.style.bottom = newFooterHeight + 'px'; 
      });

    });

  });
```

I have added this same code in 6 controllers.
Is there a way to avoid the repetition?

Comment: Move it to a service, factory, or directive

Comment: you can create a directive to handle the modal window

Comment: This Doc will give you some input into how to build and register a service.  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services  You'll need to add it as a dependency in each of your controllers that will call your modal.

Comment: @steveo I create several services in my app to call external api. Maybe the concept of service is not so clear for me. I don't have any idea how to wrap this code in a service. I try to read the doc.

Comment: Here's a Plunk of a project I'm doing if you want an example.  It calls 2 services to retrieve Json data that I send to the view.  http://plnkr.co/edit/RRPv2p4ryQgDEcFqRHHz?p=preview  If you will put a working Plunk of your project up, that will be the easiest way for me to help you refactor your code.

Comment: I try by myself now following your project. Thank you

Comment: Good luck.  If you get stuck, upload a plunk and I'll be happy to take a look at it with you.

Answer (score 1):

Probably what you are looking for is an angular service. This component is a singleton object, that you inject in every controller you need to execute this code.

[Angular Services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of a service I created to retrieve address data from a Json file. Here is the working Plunk. http://plnkr.co/edit/RRPv2p4ryQgDEcFqRHHz?p=preview

```
  angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('addressService', addressService);

  addressService.$inject = ['$q', '$timeout', '$http'];

  function addressService($q, $timeout, $http) {
    var addresses = [];

    //console.log("Number of table entries is: " + orders.length);

    var promise = $http.get('address.data.json');
    promise.then(function(response) {
      addresses = response.data;
      //  console.log("Number of table entries is now: " + orders.length);
    });

    return {
      GetAddresses: getAddresses
    };

    function getAddresses() {

      return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
        $timeout(function() {
          resolve(addresses);
        }, 2000);

      });

    }
  }
```

Here's an example of how I added dependencies for it and another service to my controller  (This is NOT the only way to do dependency injection, but is my favorite way as it is easier to read).  I then called my `addressService.GetAddresses()` from within my controller.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['smart-table']);

app.controller('TableController', TableController);

TableController.$inject = [ "orderService",  "addressService"];

function TableController( orderService, addressService) {

 addressService.GetAddresses()
  .then(function(results) {
      me.addresses = results;
     // console.log(me.addresses.length + " addresses");
    },
    function(error) {})
  .finally(function() {
    me.loadingAddresses = false;
});
  });}
```

I also had to include my .js tag in a script element on my index.html.

```
<script src="addressdata.service.js"></script>
```